# How to push to my open-source library on GitHub, when it's checked out as a submodule of a closed-source git repository?

Tags: git, authentication, github, git-submodules

Here's my situation:  I'm the maintainer of an open-source [library](https://github.com/jfriesne/muscle) on GitHub, and I also work on various closed-source (non-GitHub-based) git-repositories as part of my employment.  Many of these closed-source git repositories link to my open-source library on GitHub as a submodule.

Because of this, it's often the case that I'll be working on one of the closed-source repositories and I'll come across something that I want to change in my open-source library.  I'll make the change in the submodule and build and test it, and then I want to commit it and push the change to GitHub... and up until about four months ago that worked fine -- but recently GitHub has tightened their security policies so they no longer accept pushes from `https`-based repository-checkouts, only from `ssh`-based ones.

However, the `.gitmodules` file in my closed-source repositories are all configured to check out the open-source submodule via an `https` URL (so that my co-workers can `git submodule update --init --recursive` the submodule without having to know my GitHub login info), which means that GitHub won't let me push my changes.

For clarity, here's the relevant excerpt from one of my `.gitmodules` files:

```
[submodule "submodules/muscle"]
    path = submodules/muscle
    url = https://github.com/jfriesne/muscle.git
```

My work-around has been to keep a separate (`ssh`-based) checkout of the open source library on my machine, and manually copy any locally-changed files over to that, do a commit-and-push from there, and then go back to my submodule and do a `git stash` followed by a `git pull origin master`.  That works, but manually copying files is a bit tedious and error-prone.  I miss being able to just do a simple `cd submodules/muscle ; git commit -mblah ; git push`, as I could in the past.

My question is, is there any way to authenticate myself to GitHub so that I can push changes to the `https`-checked-out submodule directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* still push via https, you just have to use a GitHub "token" (which expires, which means you have to re-generate them now and then and update them, which is a pain).

To access GitHub via ssh even when the URL says `https://github.com/<path>`, consider using Git's `insteadOf` feature.  This particular feature is a bit confusing to configure, but is straightforward to *use* once it's done:

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/jfriesne/muscle.git.insteadOf https://github.com/jfriesne/muscle.git
```

The *value* for the configured option is the URL that will appear in some `.git/config` file's `remote.remote.url` entry.  The *name* of the configured option starts with `url` and ends with `insteadOf`, and has the usual dots, but between the two dots you insert the *replacement* URL.

(If your ssh configuration for `github.com` specifies `User git` you can omit the `git@` from the `url.replacement.insteadOf = original` setting.  The phrasing in [the git config documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) is a little confusing since it describes the fully general form, where you replace just a *prefix* of the URL, keeping the remainder: you can use this to make all `github.com` accesses use ssh, for instance.)